# Count the unique elements in an array with effective way

Tags: python

I can't release something better than: (Python 3.6)

```
N=int(input()) #count of input elements
a=[] #buffer
k=0 #counter
tel=0 #next number
for i in range(N):
    tel=int(input())
    if(not tel in a):
        a.append(tel)
        k+=1
print(k) #count of unique elements
```

But my teacher says that my solution is not very effective, coz I save data to array `a`...

Hm... He also says that I should save something in variable and permanently rewrite it.

Have You any idea un this case?

**UPD**

"Effective way" - program must uses as little memory as possible, and works fast as possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get frequency of letters in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428095/get-frequency-of-letters-in-a-sentence)

Comment: @rwp no. It is EGE exam's task. About most effective algorhytm of something. But people got my question as stupid question of stupid student. But I am not so stupid, I have really important problem, and nobody from SO can't solve it, but can give "-" to me. Great thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list into a set (which will remove any duplicates). The length of the set is how many unique elements there are in the original list.

Example:

```
print(len(set(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input())))))
```

Comment: I said that WE CAN'T USE ARRAY IN THIS TASK

Comment: Using of lists and arrays spends memory

Comment: @EgorRandomize Don't shout. The solution does not use arrays.

Comment: @EgorRandomize Your original solution in extremely poor because you used the wrong data structures. The code I provided is much more efficient both for memory and for cpu. You better pay more attention and be aware of your current, limited knowledge. Read about the Set data structure and Python generators.

Comment: @Gabriel my original solution is not effective, of course! I want you to find solution. Nobody know. I know. Stunt people sets "-" to me.

Comment: Oh. You think that I want to tell You my effective solution? But you put "-" to me. No.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do it, simple and easy to understand if your new. If you're worried about performance, don't be. its too small of a program to make a difference.

```
N=int(input()) 
a=[] 
k=0
#Don't need to create tel here! as you set it later
for i in range(N):
    tel=int(input()) #creation of tel, not updating unless already defined
    if tel != a: #simple way of what you need
        a.append(tel)
        k+=1
print(k)
```

if you want memory to be cleared after its finished, do this. but i think you will need to have an array while doing the main part!

```
N=int(input()) 
a=[] 
k=0
#Don't need to create tel here! as you set it later
for i in range(N):
    tel=int(input()) #creation of tel, not updating unless already defined
    if tel != a: #simple way of what you need
        a.append(tel)
        k+=1
a = []
print(k)
```